# List results of a competition by meet name

Tags: php, sql, database

I am attempting to list the results of a horse racing meet based on the meet's name. I would like it to look like this:

---

RACE MEET (DATE)

RACE NAME

1. Horse (sire) owned by Farm
2. Horse (sire) owned by Farm
3. Horse (sire) owned by Farm

RACE NAME

1. Horse (sire) owned by Farm
2. Horse (sire) owned by Farm

---

I have gotten it to sort of work, but it only lists the horse in 1st place and goes onto the next race. I can't figure out how to list every placing for that race.

Current Code:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM racing WHERE `meet` = '$meet' LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() . "<br />" . $sql );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 

$date= $row['date'];

echo "<h2><strong>$meet Results</strong> ($date)</h2>";

  }

?>
</h2>

<?php 

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM `racing`
WHERE `meet` = '$meet' 
GROUP BY `race`
ORDER BY `place` "; $query = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() . "<br />" . $sql );

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 

$race= $row['race'];
$place= $row['place'];
$horse= $row['horse'];
$sire= $row['sire'];
$farm= $row['farm'];

echo "

<b>$race</b><br>
$place <a href='horse.php?horse={$row['horse']}'>$horse</a> (<a href='sire.php?sire={$row['sire']}'>$sire</a>) owned by <a href='owners.php?farm={$row['farm']}'>$farm</a><br>

"; }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY race` clause is invalid in this case since there are no aggregate functions being used (ie. `COUNT()`).

Your results from that second SQL statement won't actually differentiate between each race. So your results will look as follows:

```
Race1 
1st <a href='horse.php?horse=Horse1>Horse1</a> (<a href='sire.php?sire=Sire1'>Sire1</a>) owned by <a href='owners.php?farm=Farm1'>Farm1</a><br>


Race1
2nd <a href='horse.php?horse=Horse2>Horse2</a> (<a href='sire.php?sire=Sire2'>Sire2</a>) owned by <a href='owners.php?farm=Farm2'>Farm2</a><br>
```

As you can see, it will not post the same formatting that you wanted. My recommendation would be to remove the `GROUP BY race` in your SQL query, then add a check within the last while loop to see if it's still on that race, and if it is, add the 2nd line of output, without the `race` field added.

Comment: How exactly would I accomplish that? I've tried to search for how to do a check within a loop but I can't figure out how I can accomplish that.